# Cannot Convert List to Json

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-web-api

I have the following action method:

```
public class MyDeviceController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/<controller>
    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        int userId = -1;
        List<String> myDevices1 = new List<String>();
        myDevices1.Add("1");
        >> return Json(myDevices1); << Error here           
    }
}
```

The return is underlined red with the following error:

```
cannot implicitly convert type (JsonResult to List<string>)
```

I am using Asp.net Web Api. I think its getting confused between the using System.web.http and System.mvc.http
h

Comment: there seems to be nothing wrong in your code. how are you accessing this action method? directly by a http request OR inside another action?

Comment: can you paste the code where you are getting this specific error

Comment: The good thing on using web api is that it can take care of json/xml conversions for you, check my edited answer

Answer (score 5):

your system is confusing between

```
System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult<List<string>>
```

and `System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult`

try specifiyng the full name which is System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult>

```
public System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult<List<string>> Get()
{
    int userId = -1;
    List<String> myDevices1 = new List<String>();
    myDevices1.Add("1");
    return Json(myDevices1);   
}
```

another and preferred approach would be

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    int userId = -1;
    List<String> myDevices1 = new List<String>();
    myDevices1.Add("1");
    return Request.CreateResponse(myDevices1);   
}
```

in the latter teh asp.net web api would automatically negotiate between the formats accepted by the client which is specified iin the `Accepts` header and would send XML or JSON appropriately

Comment: see what is return after that it depends upon the accepts header in the clients request

Comment: exactly, you can set your api return json by default, see my answer above

Comment: that is not the question being asked here

Comment: You are right but looking at the question, I suppose that Zapnologica wants to return JSON object without the client worrying about Accept header

Answer (score 0):

My web api project in defined class **City** JsonResult List Convert by and return.

```
     public class City
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CityName{ get; set; }
    }


    static List<City> _City = InitCitys();

    private static List<City> Citys()
    {
        var returnList = new List<City>();
        returnList.Add(new City{ Id = 0, CityName= "Sinop" });
        returnList.Add(new City{ Id = 1, CityName= "Ayancık" });
        returnList.Add(new City{ Id = 2, CityName= "İstanbul" });
        return returnList;
    }

    // GET api/values

    public JsonResult<City> Get(int Id)
    {
        var cityJsonResult = _City.Where(x => x.Id == Id).SingleOrDefault();

        return Json(cityJsonResult);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

As you are using web api:
You can leave your code this way:

```
public class MyDeviceController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/<controller>
    public List<string> Get()
    {
        int userId = -1;
        List<String> myDevices1 = new List<String>();
        myDevices1.Add("1");
        return myDevices;          
    }
}
```

By default it will return XML but
adding this line of code in `WebApiConfig.cs`, will return json by default:

```
var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
```

See more about WEB API [media Formatters](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization)

There is also another way of doing things(not the best approach):

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
    public HttpResponseMessage get(){
          List<String> myDevices1 = new List<String>();
          myDevices1.Add("1");
          JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myDevices1);

          return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, myDevices1);;
    }
```

Comment: using return type of JsonResult is a standard approach. return string instead of json and you will have to manually look after the content type and deserialization thiings.

Comment: BTW: You serialize and then throw the result away.